# passing files name to controller in spring mvc

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am allowing user to upload the xls file. 
On button click I want to pass file name to controller and want to read the file content.

Here is jsp code:

```
function uploadTemplate()
    {
        //window.location.href = "uploaduserdashboardreqmultiple";  
        String fileName = document.getElementById("filename").value;
        document.uploadRequest.action = "uploadFile?filename"+filename;
        document.uploadRequest.submit();
    }


<form:form action="" method="POST" modelAttribute="uploadFile" name="uploadRequest"  enctype="multipart/form-data">     
                    <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;">
                        <button onClick = "downloadTemplate()"  style="width:250px" type="submit" class="admin_search_btn"><spring:message code="lblDownloadXls"></spring:message></button>
                    </div>
                    <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" >                  
                        <form:input path="fileName" style="width:200px" id="filename" class="admin_search_btn" type="file" />
                         <div align="center" style="margin-bottom: 10px;" > 
                            <button onClick = "uploadTemplate()" type="submit" class="admin_search_btn"><spring:message code="lblSubmit"></spring:message></button>&nbsp;
                            <button  type="submit" class="admin_search_btn">Cancel</button>
                        </div>          
                    </div>                      
                </form:form>
```

On button click I have called function and passed file name to controller.

Controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/uploadFile")
public 
String uploadFileHandler(@ModelAttribute UploadFile uploadFile,
        @RequestParam("filename") String name
      /*  @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file*/) {

    if (!name.isEmpty()) {
        try {
            byte[] bytes = name.getBytes();

            // Creating the directory to store file
            String rootPath = System.getProperty("catalina.home");
            File dir = new File(rootPath + File.separator + "tmpFiles");
            if (!dir.exists())
                dir.mkdirs();

            // Create the file on server
            File serverFile = new File(dir.getAbsolutePath()
                    + File.separator + name);
            BufferedOutputStream stream = new BufferedOutputStream(
                    new FileOutputStream(serverFile));
            stream.write(bytes);
            stream.close();             

            return "You successfully uploaded file=" + name;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return "You failed to upload " + name + " => " + e.getMessage();
        }
    } else {
        return "You failed to upload " + name
                + " because the file was empty.";
    }
}
```

I not getting any error. But When I check in debug mode, it displays `null` for `uploadFile` and `filename`

Am I doing anything wrong ?

Comment: Are you saying the arguments passed to your handler method are `null`? That shouldn't be possible.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis: yes, it is null that is the issue

Comment: If that is the case, you would get a `NullPointerException` in the `if`. Please post the stacktrace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try with [`MultipartFile#getOriginalFilename()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html#getOriginalFilename--)

Model/Command class

```
private CommonsMultipartFile imageFile;
```

JSP/HTML:

```
<%@taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<sf:input path="imageFile" type="file" />
```

Have a look at complete [Example1](http://www.beingjavaguys.com/2013/08/spring-mvc-file-upload-example.html) and [Example2](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-mvc/spring-mvc-file-upload-example/)

---

As per your last comment, try

The below code is referred from [spring in action 3rd edition - chapter 7](http://unpherum.files.wordpress.com/2011/11/manning-spring-in-action-3rd-edition-jun-2011.pdf)

I have sample project that is used to upload an image at server. It's just a part of `registration` page of my sample project.

JSP:

```
<%@taglib prefix="sf" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<sf:form method="POST" modelAttribute="spitter"
    enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <sf:input path="imageFile" type="file" />
</sf:form>
```

Controller:

```
// first request
@RequestMapping("/signup")
public String showSpitterForm(Model model) {
    model.addAttribute("spitter", new SpitterModel());
    return "signup";
}

/*
 * Form submission for spitter registration
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/signup", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String addSpitterFromForm(
        @Valid @ModelAttribute("spitter") SpitterModel spitterModel,
        BindingResult bindingResult, HttpSession session,
        HttpServletRequest request) {
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return "signup";
    }  else {
        saveSpitter(spitterModel, session
                .getServletContext().getRealPath("/resources/upload"));
        return "redirect:list";
    }
}
```

SpitterModel:

```
import org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartFile;

public class SpitterModel  {

    private CommonsMultipartFile imageFile;

    public CommonsMultipartFile getImageFile() {
        return imageFile;
    }

    public void setImageFile(CommonsMultipartFile imageFile) {
        this.imageFile = imageFile;
    }

}
```

Method saveSpitter

```
MultipartFile file = model.getImageFile();
inputStream = file.getInputStream();
outputStream = new FileOutputStream(fullyFileName);

int readBytes = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024 * 50];
while ((readBytes = inputStream.read(buffer, 0, 1024 * 50)) != -1) {
    outputStream.write(buffer, 0, readBytes);
}
```

spring configuration file:

```
<!-- Configure the multipart resolver -->
<bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />
```

Comment: ` stream.write(bytes);` does not write the content of fire it read. Any idea?

Comment: Follow the links. Are you saving the file at server side if yes then try the updates.

Comment: what is `model` in `model.getImageFile()`

Comment: look at first line `private CommonsMultipartFile imageFile;` what I have defined in the model. It's my actual model class that is populated by spring form.

Comment: I defined it above `@mapping` but still same issue. `model`, `inputstream`, `outputstream` show `can not be resolved to a variable` error

Comment: I think you need to work on examples first. Mean while let me share you complete code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are missing to add multipartResolver bean in your servlet-context.xml file-

```
<!-- Multipart Resolver -->
<beans:bean id="multipartResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <beans:property name="maxUploadSize" value="5000000" />
        <!-- Max size in bytes. -->
    <beans:property name="maxInMemorySize" value="4096" />
    <!-- Max size in memory. -->
</beans:bean>
```

and add the given dependency in pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Instead of calling uploadTemplate() function on submit button set action attribute in form tag to uploadFile as given below-

```
<form:form action="uploadFile" method="POST" modelAttribute="uploadFile" name="uploadRequest"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
```